# Computing and storage separate deployment "show datanodes" don't show query node

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

when i use "show datanodes" in cnosdb,there is only the tskv node in the result.
my env: 1 meta 2 data(1 tskv 1 query)
modified files:

```
"echo "*** start CnosDB server 8902......"
nohup ./target/debug/cnosdb run -M tskv --config ./config/config_8902.toml 
echo "*** start CnosDB server 8912......"
nohup ./target/debug/cnosdb run -M query --config ./config/config_8912.toml
"
```

and then start the datanodes.
./run_cluster.sh
cargo run --package client --bin cnosdb-cli -- -P 8912
let's show datanodes, but the results should be this?

```
public ❯ show datanodes;
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| node_id | host      | attribute | status  | disk_free | disk_total | location   | last_updated_time   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1001    | localhost | hot       | healthy | 93.84 GB  | 245.11 GB  | /dc1/rack1 | 2024-01-27 02:15:02 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
Query took 0.025 seconds.
```

there is a bug in "show datanodes" or it's just should be this?